# How to IPC with the parent process when creating child processes in a loop (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, pipe, ipc

I have the following code snippet (a simplified representation of what I'm trying to do - training wheels). The sleep(2) would represent some network operation in my real code:

```
arr = []

5.times do |i|
     rd, wr = IO.pipe
     fork do
         sleep(2) # I'm still waiting for the sleep to happen on each process ... not good, there is no parallelism here
         rd.close
         arr[i] = i
         Marshal.dump(arr, wr)
     end
     wr.close
     result = rd.read
     arr = Marshal.load(result)
end

# Process.waitall
p arr
```

Q: is it possible to somehow create new processes in a loop, pass the results back but not waiting on each iteration. I'm pretty rusty and don't know / remember a great deal about IPC ... especially in Ruby.

- Actual result is wait time of 2s*5 = 10s
- Expected ~2s tootal (async processing of the sleep())

So a good comment clarifying things, explaining the theory would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you wait for each child process to write its results to the pipe before starting the next iteration.

The simplest fix would be to save the read ends of the pipes in an array and don’t `read` any of them until the loop is finished and you’ve started all the child processes:

```ruby
arr = []
# array to store the IOs
pipes = []

5.times do |i|
  rd, wr = IO.pipe
  fork do
    sleep(2)
    rd.close
    # Note only returning the value of i here, not the whole array
    Marshal.dump(i, wr)
  end

  wr.close
  #store the IO for later
  pipes[i] = rd
end

# Now all child processes are started, we can read the results in turn
# Remember each child is returng i, not the whole array
pipes.each_with_index do |rd, i|
    arr[i] = Marshal.load(rd.read)
end
```

A more complex solution if the wait/network times for different child processes variad might be to look at [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-select), so you could read from whichever pipe was ready first.